# Google Cloud Authentication Service-to-service with JWT token

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

### Updated question:

Is it possible to craft JWT token from application `A` and verify it in
application `B` using GCP service accounts? How can I do that in Python?

Both applications are deployed in GCP. Applications can be deployed within GCF, Cloud Run, AppEngine, GKE or even in GCE.

### Original question:

I spent some time reading Google Cloud documentation but I don't find a "generic" answer of how to handle authentication between services. (most probably because they are not the same for each GCP product)

So how do I authenticate my services between each other considering that we put aside any of Google's serveless products that ease authentication validation? (e.g. Cloud Run/CF that checks token automatically)

I almost found a solution by [signing JWTs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signJwt)
but I was unable to verify the token afterwards.

A good solution would be something that looks like:

```
def serviceA():
"""
serviceA function gets a token and pass it in it's request to the serviceB
"""
    token = # How do I retrieved a token that I can use to auth my call? ID Token? Signed JWT?
    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {token}")

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()
```

and in another service, let's say `serviceB`

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
"""Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
  if "Authorization" not in request.headers:
    return "Forbidden", 403
  # Check if the request is authenticated
  verify_token(request.headers)
  # proceed...
```

Here's some usefull ressources I have been through before asking this question:

- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#python
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#identity_tokens
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#requesting_short-lived_credentials
- https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation behind this functionality? Why do you want authentication between services?

Comment: Because I am convinced of implementing a Zero Trust security model, therefore I want all my applications to prove their identity even if they are deployed in a trusted environment.

Answer (score 1):

The only service fitting your use case that I can think of is [BeyondCorp](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp):

> BeyondCorp is Google's implementation of the zero trust model
> (...)
> BeyondCorp allows for single sign-on, access control policies, access proxy, and user- and device-based authentication and authorization.
> The BeyondCorp principles are:
> -Access to services must not be determined by the network from which you connect
> -Access to services is granted based on contextual factors from the user and their device
> -Access to services must be authenticated, authorized, and encrypted

Comment: Answer concerns the correct topic but I am looking for a solution to authenticate service-to-service within GCP. I will reformulate my question as I suspect it is unclear.

Comment: Does [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) fit your use case?

Comment: Yes, service accounts fits my use case. Is there a way to generate a token without injecting it's private key and still be secure? (I don't think so but if I can avoid managing private keys, would be perfect!)

Comment: As far as I know there is no service that would 100% fit your bill. You can file a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) to have it added to GCP.